# Silex - Deny access to client from server side

Tags: php, symfony, silex

On the server side I am receiving a request with a Uri path the client would like to access with a token in the header. My server will look at the `hostname` and `token` and make sure they are valid. If they aren't, I want to stop the client from accessing the API endpoint.

Here is the function

```
$app->before(function(Request $request) use ($app) {
    $host = $request->getHost();
    $token = $request->headers->get('token');

    if(!$app['isValidTokenService']($token)) {
        $app['monolog']->addInfo(sprintf("%s is a invalid token", $token));
        return $app->abort(401,'Unauthorized - bad credentials');
        //return new Response('Unauthorized - invalid ****',401);
    }

    if(!$app['isValidHostService']($host)) {
        $app['monolog']->addInfo(sprintf("%s is a invalid host", $host));
        return $app->abort(401,'Unauthorized - invalid host');
        //return new Response('Unauthorized - invalid ****',401);
    }

    return 'test';
});
```

I tried doing a `return new Response('Unauthorized - invalid ****',401);` which allowed the user to still access the end point. The $app->abort() seems to be working like a charm but its not responding to the client with anything which I am assuming its not the proper way of handling this situation.

How do I properly handle this situation to deny access to the API endpoint and return a proper error code to my client.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry Joshua, I couldn't reproduce your problem:

```
$ mkdir silex-test
$ cd silex-test
$ composer require silex/silex phpunit/phpunit
$ mkdir tests
```

Now create a file inside the tests folder *appTest.php*:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Silex\Application;

class appTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testBeforeFilterPriorToRouteMatching()
    {
        $app = new Application();

        $app->before(function () {
            return new Response('before');
        });

        $app->get('/', function() { return new Response('you should never see me!'); });

        $request = Request::create('/');
        $this->assertEquals('before', $app->handle($request)->getContent(), "before test didn't canceled the execution!");

    }
}
```

Now just execute the test:

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit tests/appTest.php
PHPUnit 4.8.7 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.

Time: 201 ms, Memory: 6.00Mb

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

As you can see the controller for the / route was never called, so Silex is working as expected.

This only brings me the question: Which version are you using? (I've tried this with 1.3 and dev-master which is 2.0@dev) [This PR](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/pull/525) (a little dated, though) solved and issue with the *before* middleware.

## Update

In the above code, I've tried to shown that the `return new Response('before')` does indeed cancels all other execution. If you take a look at the assertion:

```
$this->assertEquals('before', $app->handle($request)->getContent(), "before test didn't canceled the execution!");
```

I compare the result of handling one request to the / URI which should return the string `you should never see me!` but it return the string `before` because the `before` filter returns a response with the string `before` and the controller code for the route path / is never called.

If you want to double check, change the controller code to:

```
$app->get('/', function() { 
    echo "You'll never see me as this is not called because of the before filter";

    return new Response('you should never see me!'); 
});
```

And check that running the test (`vendor/bin/phpunit tests/appTest.php`) never outputs the string *You'll never see me as this is not called because of the before filter* because the controller code is never called.

Comment: I don't understand your test results. The `return new Response('before');` should cancel all actions after this?

Comment: I figure out the problem. I was using the wrong include `Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Response;`.

Comment: @JoshuaDalley, glad you make it.